# Applying the Ricci identity on the Cotton tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, conformal-geometry

The Schouten tensor is given by
$$
P_{i j}=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(R_{i j}-\frac{1}{2(n-2)} R g_{i j}\right).$$

I want to compute the divergence of the Bach tensor in dimension $4$. From [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382967/trace-and-divergence-of-the-bach-tensor) post, we know that the Bach tensor is divergence-free in dimension $4.$ I want to show it explicitly.

The divergence of the back tensor

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla^{j} B_{i j} &=\nabla^{j} ( \nabla^{k} \nabla_{k} P_{i j}-\nabla^{j} \nabla^{k} \nabla_{j} P_{i k})+\nabla^{j}\left(P^{k l} W_{i k j l}\right)  \\
&= (\nabla^{j} \nabla^{k} \nabla_{k} P_{i j}-\nabla^{k} \nabla^{j} \nabla_{k} P_{i j})+\nabla^{j}\left(P^{k l} W_{i k j l}\right) \end{aligned} .$$ The second term requires the divergence of the Weyl tensor, and I have a nice formula for the divergence of the Weyl tensor. I'm struggling to compute the following portion:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\nabla^{j} \nabla^{k} \nabla_{k} P_{i j}-\nabla^{k} \nabla^{j} \nabla_{k} P_{i j}) \end{aligned} .$$

On page 126 of Jiaqi Chen's Doctoral [thesis](https://escholarship.org/content/qt9x65d5dq/qt9x65d5dq_noSplash_849c7f2ce4c7f13dc7df682139c9ae09.pdf?t=qiwqjt), he says the Ricci identity gives us

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\nabla^{j} \nabla^{k} \nabla_{k} P_{i j}-\nabla^{k} \nabla^{j} \nabla_{k} P_{i j}) \end{aligned} $$ equals to $$(\nabla^{j} P^{k l}) R_{i k j l}.$$ I could not derive this equality by the [Ricci Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754430/proving-the-ricci-identity). Could you help me establish the equality that Jiaqi Chen claimed? Thanks so much. Note that here our connection $\nabla$ is torsion-free and metric compatible.

Update: Finally, I did the calculation and it was nasty. I'm still wondering how Dr. Chen did this in just two lines. I'm still looking for a better/short calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ricci identity gives

\begin{align*}
 (\nabla^j\nabla^k - \nabla^k\nabla^j)\nabla_k P_{ij} & = R^{jk}{}_k{}^l \nabla_l P_{ij} + R^{jk}{}_i{}^l \nabla_k P_{lj} + R^{jk}{}_j{}^l \nabla_k P_{il} \\
 & = -R^{jl}\nabla_l P_{ij} + R_{jkil}\nabla^kP^{jl} + R^{kl}\nabla_kP_{il} \\
 & = R_{jkil}\nabla^kP^{jl} .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much.